# Java Iterable object won't Iterate correctly

Tags: java, iterable

I have a java object that implements the Iterable interface. This linked list has a group of objects that each hold a parameterized object (so it could be a String OR an ArrayList or whatever).

In the iterator() method, i create an Iterator object that takes an array of these parameterized items and return it.

However, when i use the following code:

```
//create an Iterable object named 'iterate'
for(String current : iterate){
//try to do some stuff with it... print it out?
}

//more code
```

//here is how i implemented the iterator function of my Iterable class:

```
public Iterator<Item> iterator(){
   // return an iterator over items in order from front to end
    Item[] items = (Item[]) new Object[numberOfItems];
    QueueItem<Item> item = first;
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfItems;i++){
        items[i] = item.getInfo();
        item = item.next;
    }
    return new myIterator(items);
}

//here is the code for the myIterator class. it is a private internal class

private class myIterator implements Iterator<Item>{

    Item items[];
    int index;
    public myIterator(Item current[]){
        items = current;
        index = 0;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if(items==null){
            return false;
        }
        return (index>=items.length);
    }

    @Override
    public Item next() {
        if(index+1>=items.length){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("There are no more elements!");
        }
        return items[index++];
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("this operation is not supported");
    }

}
```

the code goes to the for loop, then creates the Iterator object correctly (I used breakpoints to confirm), and returns it, but then the code jumps out of the for loop without going through it even once and continues....

Am i missing something? did i do something wrong here? how do i need to change the implementation of my Iterable object? is there some GOTCHA with implementing this that i'm not taking into account?

thanks!

Comment: show how you are implementing new Iterator instance

Comment: You'd have to show some real code to have a valid question.

Comment: i added the code above. i added what i thought was pertinent. let me know if you need more....

Comment: Maybe numberOfItems is equals to 0 ?

Comment: that isn't it. i put a breakpoint in the Iterator construction code. it goes through and gets the correct array, just how i want it. However, the foreach construct doesn't do anything with it!

Comment: oh my gosh. so embarrassing. the hasNext method had the boolean statement reversed. it should have been:
    
    return (index<items.length);

thanks anyways! i've been pulling my hair out about this. i debugged everything else, then it dawned on me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `hasNext` method you check if `return (index>=items.length);` Well this will return false. change operant to `"<"`

Answer (score 0):

oh my gosh. so embarrassing. the hasNext method had the boolean statement reversed.

it should have been:

```
return (index<items.length); thanks anyways!
```

i've been pulling my hair out about this. i debugged everything else, then it dawned on me.

This is my first iterator implementation, so i figured it must have been something more fundamental that i wasn't doing correctly.

Comment: Instead of writing a new answer which is the same as the one already posted, you should just upvote/accept the first one.

Comment: sorry. when i came back to this thread that answer wasn't there. i left my answer for posterity, not to accept my own answer necessarily. i'm not THAT big of a megalomaniac! thanks for the feedback.